# How to determine printing edition of Robert Crumb's The People's Comics?

Tags: comics

I have a copy of Robert Crumb's *The People's Comics*.  On the inside of cover at the bottom of the page it reads:

> **THE PEOPLE'S COMICS.** Copyright (c) 1972 by R. Crumb.  Published by Kitchen Sink Enterprises, a division of Krupp Comic Works, Inc., P.O. Box 7, Princeton, Wisconsin 54968. Phone (414) 295-3972. Free catalog upon request. This edition was published in cooperation with Terry Zwigoff (Golden Gate Publishing Co.) First printing of this edition, April 1976. Printing No. 5 4 3

Is this a first edition, if not, what edition is it?

Here is the cover:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Comicbooks.org](https://www.comics.org/issue/1035982/), you have a *4th* printing from 1979. The cover price hidden by the $1.50 sticker is $1. This is also backed up by [MyComicShop](https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=145501).

[image]

> 4th print February 1979 has 1.00 USD cover price. Says printing 543. Third Kitchen Sink printing.

Purely for reference, if your comic was in *[absolute mint](http://www.csub.edu/~rdaniels/Comic%20Book%20Grading%20&%20Values.htm)* condition it would be worth about what you paid for it.